# add class to js element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In the following code, how can I add a class to each of the location markers? I need to add a class so that I can then trigger different images on hover for both markers.

I have a text box to the right of this map so, when you hover on each line of text i want it to highlight the correlating map maker and change the marker image.

```js
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
  center: [2.143, 41.388],
  zoom: 12
});

// code from the next step will go here!
var geojson = {
  type: 'Locations',
  features: [{
      type: 'Location',
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [2.174520, 41.388851]
      },
      properties: {
        title: 'TRAFALGAR 6',
        description: 'Carrer De Trafalgar, 6, 08010 Barcelona, Spain'
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'Location',
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [2.109630, 41.383520]
      },
      properties: {
        title: 'JUAN CARLOS FAIRMONT',
        description: 'Avinguda Diagonal, 661 671, 08028 Barcelona, Spain'
      }
    }
  ]
};

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
        offset: 25
      }) // add popups
      .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
    .addTo(map);
});

// disable map zoom when using scroll
map.scrollZoom.disable();

// Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl({
  showCompass: false,
  showZoom: true
});

map.addControl(nav, "top-left");
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.marker {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.glitch.com/83d2fce6-58e7-4b74-8ce5-b1a43ae0945a/thumbnails/unnamed.png?1592467484333');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marker:hover {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.glitch.com/83d2fce6-58e7-4b74-8ce5-b1a43ae0945a/Elijah logo.png?1592453844803');
}
```

```html
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title></title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: You can access `mapboxgl-popup-content` after click

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

- You can access the markers as `mapboxgl-canvas-container marker`

---

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("mapboxgl-canvas-container marker")]
  .forEach((marker,i) => marker.id = "marker"+i)
```

---

- You can access `mapboxgl-popup-content` after click

---

```
document.getElementById("map").addEventListener("mouseover",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("mapboxgl-popup-content")) {
    // tgt.style.border="3px solid red";
    if (!tgt.id) tgt.id = tgt.querySelector("h3").textContent.replace(/\s+/g,"_");
  }
})
```

```js
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
  center: [2.143, 41.388],
  zoom: 12
});

// code from the next step will go here!
var geojson = {
  type: 'Locations',
  features: [{
      type: 'Location',
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [2.174520, 41.388851]
      },
      properties: {
        title: 'TRAFALGAR 6',
        description: 'Carrer De Trafalgar, 6, 08010 Barcelona, Spain'
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'Location',
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [2.109630, 41.383520]
      },
      properties: {
        title: 'JUAN CARLOS FAIRMONT',
        description: 'Avinguda Diagonal, 661 671, 08028 Barcelona, Spain'
      }
    }
  ]
};

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
        offset: 25
      }) // add popups
      .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
    .addTo(map);
});

// disable map zoom when using scroll
map.scrollZoom.disable();

// Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl({
  showCompass: false,
  showZoom: true
});

map.addControl(nav, "top-left");

document.getElementById("map").addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("mapboxgl-popup-content")) {
    // tgt.style.border="3px solid red";
    if (!tgt.id) tgt.id = tgt.querySelector("h3").textContent.replace(/\s+/g, "_")
  }
});
[...document.querySelectorAll(".mapboxgl-canvas-container .marker")].forEach((marker, i) => marker.id = "marker" + (i+1))

const hoverIt = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.id === "rollover1" || tgt.id === "rollover2") {
    const type = e.type
    const over = type === "mouseenter";
    const id = "marker"+tgt.id.replace("rollover","");
    document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("hovered",over); // this does nothing to the flag!
  }  
};

document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseenter",hoverIt)
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseleave",hoverIt)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.marker {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.glitch.com/83d2fce6-58e7-4b74-8ce5-b1a43ae0945a/thumbnails/unnamed.png?1592467484333');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marker:hover {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.glitch.com/83d2fce6-58e7-4b74-8ce5-b1a43ae0945a/Elijah logo.png?1592453844803');
}

#TRAFALGAR_6 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#marker1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#marker1.hovered { background-image = url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0051/9628/3977/t/7/assets/pf-b3c6e0ef--Locationshero.jpg?v=1589772232) }

#marker2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#marker2.hovered { background-image = url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0051/9628/3977/t/7/assets/pf-fdd801e3--Fairmont.jpg?v=1589773965) }
```

```html
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title></title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id='map'></div>

<div class="sc-pkUyL fTyjzF pf-f382b2d9" id="container" data-pf-type="Column" style="background-image: none;">
  <h3 data-pf-type="Heading" class="sc-oTLFK lcHmGL pf-d8a72a12"><span data-pf-type="Text" class="sc-ptSuy fnmilh pf-80d8a72a">LOCATIONS</span></h3>
  <h3 id="rollover1" data-pf-type="Heading" class="sc-oTLFK lcHmGL pf-129e995e locationstext"><a data-color="inherit" href="/pages/trafalgar-6" target="_self"><span data-pf-type="Text" class="sc-ptSuy fnmilh pf-2a129e99">TRAFALGAR 6</span></a></h3>
  <h3 id="rollover2" data-pf-type="Heading" class="sc-oTLFK lcHmGL pf-5ef382b2 locationstext"><span data-pf-type="Text" class="sc-ptSuy fnmilh pf-995ef382">JUAN CARLOS FAIRMONT</span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think this is what I require, I just need to add ID's to the 2 location markers, so I can call them in CSS. Currently both markers are being styled class .marker....so i need them to have individual ID's

Comment: SO change 
`if (!tgt.id) tgt.id = tgt.querySelector("h3").textContent` now the marker has ID "TRAFALGAR 6"

Comment: but the ID cant have whitespace?

Comment: It can, but you can replace the space if you wish `tgt.querySelector("h3").textContent.replace(/\s+/g,"_")`

Comment: ok, im a bit confused by this...i added the previous bit of code to the map and it broke it (didnt show up at all)... if you dont mind, could you add this into the code above so i can see it please

Comment: See update. I add a border to `TRAFALGAR_6` and assign on hover

Comment: ok thanks, but this has added the class to the popup box, not the marker itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216199/discussion-between-gjjr-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I changed the code. It DOES what it says, but it is irrelevant since the marker is the flag and you cannot see the background image of the flag